# Is it safe to uninstall thunderbird?

Tags: uninstall, thunderbird

Actually I don't want it, I also don't want to install any updates of Thunderbird.

So, whenever new updates available to download, I will manually deselect it from downloading.

Thanks

Comment: Yes. But I would rather you use `sudo aptitude purge thunderbird`, it's much cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 18):

Yes, it is completely safe to remove Mozilla Thunderbird. To do so, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge thunderbird*
```

Answer (score 5):

You can remove Thunderbird:

1. open terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Run this command:`sudo apt-get remove --purge thunderbird -y`
3. Exit terminal: `exit`

Comment: Thank you for your support